# JavaScript store all URLs in the same format (http, https, www.)

Tags: javascript

I am a JR backend developer, and haven't done much work with JS in quite some time. I am trying to store all URLs in the same format, for ex.)

```
www.hello.com
hello.com
http://hello.com
https://hello.com
```

Right now if i just type `hello.com`, it comes back as `http://www.hello.com`, which is awesome!

But how can I add to this function to store `www.hello.com` as `http://www.hello.com`, as well?

Right now, I am getting `http://www.www.hello.com`. I'm sure there is a way to maybe strip the additional www. OR reconfig the function a little?

```
        function checkURL(abc){
            string = abc.value
            if(!(/^http:\/\//.test(string))){
                string = "http://www." + string;
            }

            abc.value=string

}
```

## edit

So my major issue here, is that in the backend (I'm a Python/Django dev), I am using the URL as a POST request in a user form. I want to store these URLs basically all in the same format( Whichever format makes the most sense), because I am using the URL as a potential company match. So I would like `hello.com` and `www.hello.com` and even `http://hello.com`, to all be saved in the same format, to which my company match gets triggered when querying the DB. I thought a JS function would definitely be the way to go here. I don't need `www`, but I do need these stored in the same format.

Comment: Either test the string to see if it starts with "www." before adding it, or remove it if it exists: `string = "http://www." + string.replace(/$www\./, '');`

Comment: Not many sites use www any more ...do you really need it?

Comment: One thing to note: not all domains are configured to handle the `www.` prefix.

Comment: It's been a while since I've tested it, but some time back you needed to add `www` to `.gov` sites.

Comment: @ScottMarcus just tested using `data.gov` and it did resolve to `www.data.gov`. My guess is that most of them would do same for whatever that is worth

Comment: "Right now if i just type `hello.com`, it comes back as `http://www.hello.com`, which is awesome" — If you type it into a browser's address bar it comes back as `https://hello.com/en/index.html`

Comment: @charlietfl — `data.gov` is treated by a browser as `http://data.gov` but then the HTTP server responds with a 302 redirect to `https://data.gov/` and then *that* gets another 302 redirect response to `https://www.data.gov/`.

Comment: @Quentin Right, that was sort of my point

Comment: @charlietfl — You can't assume that every server will do the same thing though. You have to just do what the browser would do, assume `http://` and no other changes, and then let redirects take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is possibly the answer you're looking for:

```js
/**
  @param str = URL to be parsed
  @param options = can contain "withHttp", "withHttps" or "withWWW" booleans
**/

const parseUrl = (str = '', options = {}) => {
  const [tld, domain, ...sub] = str.replace(/https?\:\/\//gi, '').split('.').reverse();

  const protocol = (options.withHttp || options.withHttps) ? (options.withHttps) ? 'https://' : 'http://' : '';
  const subDomain = (options.withWWW) ? 'www.' : (sub.length) ? `${sub}.` : '';

  return `${protocol}${subDomain}${domain}.${tld}`;
};

console.log(parseUrl('hello.com', {withHttps: true, withWWW: true}) === 'https://www.hello.com');
```

The idea is that by default, only http/https protocol is removed and *subdomain.domain.tld* structure is left untouched. However, with options you can define what is the final output based on the input.

If you explicitly want to omit subdomain (or "www."), then you need to extend that functionality into `parseUrl` by yourself.

Try it and extend it by yourself, but this should do the job based on your current question.